# python script to run splunk query and get output as text output

Tags: python, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-api

Trying to run below code it executes but I do not get the correct value any help is appreciated expecting single value like 492. Code runs but does not give the correct value. Tried splunk library but unable to use those.

```
import urllib
import httplib2 #import library
import json
import pprint
import time
import re
from xml.dom import minidom

searchquery = 'search index="movable_in" sourcetype="movable:in:assets" | stats avg(exposure_score)'

myhttp = httplib2.Http()
baseurl = 'https://xxxx.splunkxxx.com:8089'
usernamesp = 'xxxx'
passwordsp = 'xxxx'


def get_splunk_result(searchquery):
    # Step 1: Get a session key
    servercontent = myhttp.request(f'{baseurl}/services/auth/login', 'POST', headers={},
                                   body=urllib.parse.urlencode({'username': usernamesp, 'password': passwordsp}))[1]
    sessionkey = minidom.parseString(servercontent).getElementsByTagName('sessionKey')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    # print ("====>sessionkey:  %s  <====" % sessionkey)
    sid = ''
    # ------------------
    if not searchquery.startswith('search'):
        searchquery = f'search {searchquery}'

    # Step 2: Get a sid with the search query
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            searchjob = myhttp.request(f'{baseurl}/services/search/jobs', 'POST',
                                       headers={F'Authorization': F'Splunk %s' % sessionkey},
                                       body=urllib.parse.urlencode({'search': searchquery}))[1]
            sid = minidom.parseString(searchjob).getElementsByTagName('sid')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            break
        except:
            i = i + 1
            # print(i)
            if (i > 30): break
    # print("====>SID:  %s  <====" % sid)
    # Step 3: Get search status

    myhttp.add_credentials(usernamesp, passwordsp)
    servicessearchstatusstr = '/services/search/jobs/%s/' % sid

    isnotdone = True
    while isnotdone:
        searchstatus = myhttp.request(f'{baseurl}{servicessearchstatusstr}', 'GET')[1]
        isdonestatus = re.compile('isDone">(0|1)')
        strstatus = str(searchstatus)
        isdonestatus = isdonestatus.search(strstatus).groups()[0]
        if (isdonestatus == '1'):
            isnotdone = False
# Step 4: Get the search result

    services_search_results_str = '/services/search/jobs/%s/results?output_mode=json_rows&count=0' % sid
    searchresults = myhttp.request(f'{baseurl}{services_search_results_str}', 'GET')[1]

    searchresults = json.loads(searchresults)
    # searchresults = splunk_result(searchresults)
    return searchresults


output = get_splunk_result(searchquery)
print(output)
```

Comment: What incorrect value do you get?  Why can you not use the Splunk library?

Comment: Have no idea how to use that i need a script preferably python which runs a query and gives the response did check splunk library but did not work so far for me.

Comment: "did not work so far for me" is not a thing we can help you with - what have you tried? What error(s) have you received? What do you *expect* for results?

Comment: getting output {'preview': False, 'init_offset': 0, 'messages': [], 'fields': ['avg(exposure_score)'], 'rows': [['529.5385045300148']]}

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Is there a way to filter above like get value of rows only and exclude everything else.

Comment: Got this working only output is in json

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import urllib
import httplib2 #import library
import json
import pprint
import time
import re
from xml.dom import minidom

searchquery = 'search index="movable_in" sourcetype="movable:in:assets" | stats avg(exposure_score)'

myhttp = httplib2.Http()
baseurl = 'https://xxxx.splunkxxx.com:8089'
usernamesp = 'xxxx'
passwordsp = 'xxxx'


def get_splunk_result(searchquery):
    # Step 1: Get a session key
    servercontent = myhttp.request(f'{baseurl}/services/auth/login', 'POST', headers={},
                                   body=urllib.parse.urlencode({'username': usernamesp, 'password': passwordsp}))[1]
    sessionkey = minidom.parseString(servercontent).getElementsByTagName('sessionKey')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    # print ("====>sessionkey:  %s  <====" % sessionkey)
    sid = ''
    # ------------------
    if not searchquery.startswith('search'):
        searchquery = f'search {searchquery}'

    # Step 2: Get a sid with the search query
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            searchjob = myhttp.request(f'{baseurl}/services/search/jobs', 'POST',
                                       headers={F'Authorization': F'Splunk %s' % sessionkey},
                                       body=urllib.parse.urlencode({'search': searchquery}))[1]
            sid = minidom.parseString(searchjob).getElementsByTagName('sid')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            break
        except:
            i = i + 1
            # print(i)
            if (i > 30): break
    # print("====>SID:  %s  <====" % sid)
    # Step 3: Get search status

    myhttp.add_credentials(usernamesp, passwordsp)
    servicessearchstatusstr = '/services/search/jobs/%s/' % sid

    isnotdone = True
    while isnotdone:
        searchstatus = myhttp.request(f'{baseurl}{servicessearchstatusstr}', 'GET')[1]
        isdonestatus = re.compile('isDone">(0|1)')
        strstatus = str(searchstatus)
        isdonestatus = isdonestatus.search(strstatus).groups()[0]
        if (isdonestatus == '1'):
            isnotdone = False
# Step 4: Get the search result

    services_search_results_str = '/services/search/jobs/%s/results?output_mode=json_rows&count=0' % sid
    searchresults = myhttp.request(f'{baseurl}{services_search_results_str}', 'GET')[1]

    searchresults = json.loads(searchresults)
    # searchresults = splunk_result(searchresults)
    return searchresults


output = get_splunk_result(searchquery)
print(output)
```

Comment: Tried this code but does not get output

Comment: put this into your original post instead of as an answer (since it's not an answer)

Comment: Got this working only output is in json